# QuickSight parseJson with dots in key

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jsonpath, amazon-quicksight

In AWS QuickSight, I'm trying to create a Calculated Field based on some JSON data. The data has dots in some of the keys, e.g:

```
{"foo.bar": "baz"}
```

In order to parse this, I'd need something like the bracket notation, since the dot notation won't work (unless there's a way to escape the dot?):

```
parseJson({the_column}, '$["foo.bar"]')
```

Trying this out, I'm getting errors saying that the syntax is incorrect.

So, my question: What is the correct syntax to achieve this?

Note:
I *can* use `replace` to at least be able to parse it, e.g `parseJson(replace({the_field}, "foo.bar", "whatever"), "$.whatever")`. But this does not seem optimal, and it is prone to errors like accidentally replacing the wrong string.

Comment: The documentation is not clear and only mentions the most basic path syntax (not sure if it is even justified to call this JSONPath?)  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parseJson-function.html
Maybe this works: `parseJson({the_column}, "$['foo.bar']")` I cannot test it myself.